# Can't close the window with button: QML

Tags: qt, qml

I've created an item, that contains a button. I'm trying to close parent window of item with this button, but I'm getting this message, when click the item:

> TypeError: Property 'close' of object QQuickRootItem(0x1d8efed8) is not
>   a function

Can you help me with this?

Code of item:

```
import QtQuick 2.4

Item {

    id: backButton

    ItemForButton{

        id: baseButton
        text: "Back"

        onClicked: {

            backButton.parent.close()
        }

    }

}
```

Code for window:

```
Window {

        id: window
        visible: true
        BackButton {

        }
        x: 30
        y: 30
    }
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

That seems a bit messy.  If I were you, I'd add a clicked signal to the custom button type.  For example:

Item:

```
import QtQuick 2.4

Item {
    id: backButton

    // Add a clicked signal here
    signal clicked()

    ItemForButton{

        id: baseButton
        text: "Back"

        onClicked: {
            // Emit the new clicked signal here:
            backButton.clicked();
        }
    }
}
```

Window:

```
Window {
    id: window
    visible: true

    BackButton {
        // Respond to the signal here.
        onClicked: window.close();
    }
}
```

This provides the flexibility of using your custom BackButton type in other ways in the future.

Comment: This question does not answer why backButton's parent is not a Window. I think one should know that Window is not a `QQuickItem`, and therefore cannot be a `parent` (the property, not a function) for any `QQuickItem`.

Comment: I've already done like you wrote. Thank you. It seems, that my code can't be done because of scope.